# MS Lists - Create column with options based on a another column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, mslists

I am new to MS Lists.

I would like to create a column (B) with choices depending on column (A).

**Example**:

Column A (Location). Items: Lab 1, Lab 2, Lab 3, Lab 4, Device

Column B (Equipment ID). Items: Choices filtered based on location choice chosen in Column A.

Happy New Year and many thanks in advance.

Comment: did you thought of doing this on a second list and add a lookup column instead of choice column ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a cascading list in the SharePoint with Power Apps.

**References**:

[Working with Cascading Lists in SharePoint and Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/working-with-cascading-lists-in-sharepoint-and-powerapps#3-power-apps-filter-choices)